# Get a list of a Page's public events without client-side auth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there any way to use FQL/Graph to retrieve a list of events created on my page to display on my website?

These events are all public, so the client's permissions should not matter, but nonetheless Facebook requires an access_token for any event query.

Have I any simple alternatives to forcing the client to authorise the app (clearly not acceptable.)

I have read a little bit about offline_access tokens, but I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

Create a facebook app, go to Facebook's [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), choose your application on the top right dropdown menu, click "Get Access Token".

You'll only need **offline_access** in addition to the basic permissions. Offline access gives you a permanent access token (as long as you don't revoke it).

Copy the access token and use it in your website to make Graph API requests.

Comment: FB.init({
        appId: '_____',
        autoLogAppEvents: true,
        xfbml: true,
        status: true,
        access_token: "______"
        version: 'v2.12'
    });            Does the access token go in the FB.init like this?